# MySQL error: HAVING is not valid at this position, expecting EOF, ';'

Tags: mysql, sql

Im having that problem in this specific line:

```
SELECT city, SUM(credit_limit) AS total_limit 
FROM table 
GROUP BY city 
ORDER BY total_limit 
HAVING SUM(credit_limit) < 110000;
```

Probably is a stupid error, but im not seeing a syntax problem here.

Comment: `HAVING` goes between `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)?

Comment: SQL is very restrictive about the orders of things. Even though it seems like it shouldn't matter, you have to put everything in the order that the specification says.

Comment: Thanks, it really didn't look like the order was going to change anything, im learning yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT city, SUM(credit_limit) AS total_limit
FROM table
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY total_limit
**WHERE** SUM(credit_limit) < 110000;

Comment: you need to change HAVING to WHERE to filter the results